# table plot in R adjusting the axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot this table

```
         1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
  X0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 163   0   0  78   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0 153   0
  X1   0   0   0   0   0 152 123   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   1   0   0   0   0 119   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  X2   0   0  55   0   0   1   0   0 185   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0 154   0   0   0
  X3   1   1   0   0 149   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   4   0   4 126   0   0   0   0   0 108   1   5   0   0
  X4   0   0   0  16   0   1   0 108   0 110   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  X5  13   0   0   0   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0 138   0 123   7   0   0   0   1   0  18   0  93   0   0
  X6   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  85   1   0   0   0   1   0   0 104 100 104   0   0   2   0   0
  X7   0  93  23   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  71   0   0   0   0   0  55   0   0   0  55   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 103
  X8 245   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  73   7   0  12   1   0   0   0   1   1   4   0  48   8   0
  X9   0   0   0 153   0  11   1  15   0  18   0   1 194   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

      30
  X0   0
  X1   0
  X2   0
  X3   0
  X4 162
  X5   0
  X6   0
  X7   0
  X8   0
  X9   5
```

but cannot make visually clear what the table is showing, as the y-axis get smudged due to the number of columns in table.

[image]

Is it possible somehow to plot this in a way that axis are clear, and nothing get smudged together?

```
> dput(tablen)
structure(c(4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 245L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 93L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 55L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 153L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 149L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 152L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 123L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 108L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 185L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 110L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 71L, 0L, 0L, 163L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 194L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 85L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 78L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 73L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 138L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 55L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 123L, 
0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 126L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
119L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 55L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 104L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 100L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
104L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 108L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 154L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
93L, 2L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 153L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 103L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 162L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L), .Dim = c(10L, 30L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9"
    ), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30")), .Names = c("", 
"")), class = "table")
```

Comment: Please provide the otput of `dput(<yourmatrix>)` in the question and show the code that produces this plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rotate the y-axis labels (see `help("par")` for documentation:

```
plot(tablen, las = 1)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Well, define exactly what kind of graph you would like to create and we could talk about how to achieve that. As it is I'm not sure what you expect.